# max function applied to a Serie

Tags: python, max

A dataframe includes many items, including close, high and low items in a size of (50k+, 20)
In order to compute the true range and then the ATR, I have to compute the max between tr1, tr2 and tr3 as described below :  `tr1 = (dataTrad['high'] - dataTrad['low'])  tr2 = abs(dataTrad['high'] - dataTrad['close'].shift(1))   tr3 = abs(dataTrad['low'] - dataTrad['close'].shift(1))`
I tried the max() function but get an error message
I also tried the numpy maximum function, that causes a crash of the spyder kernel...
I am a bit lost on what route is available for computing this maximum without a loop.
Any idea ?
Thanks a lot in advance.

dataTrad is a DataFrame (60946, 13)here is a bit of the code :

```
    connect = sq.connect('test.db')
    cursor = connect.cursor()
    trlist = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM TRdataindex", connect)
    dataTrad = trlist.rename(columns={"Price Open": "open", "Price Close": "close", "Price High": "high", "Price Low": "low", "Volume": "volume", "index": "reindex" })
    dataTrad.drop(dataTrad[pd.isnull(dataTrad["close"])].index, inplace=True)            
    dataTrad.drop(dataTrad[pd.isnull(dataTrad["open"])].index, inplace=True)
    dataTrad.drop(dataTrad[pd.isnull(dataTrad["high"])].index, inplace=True)
    dataTrad.drop(dataTrad[pd.isnull(dataTrad["low"])].index, inplace=True)            
   # ATR - Average True Range 
    tr1 = (dataTrad['high'] - dataTrad['low'])
    tr2 = abs(dataTrad['high'] - dataTrad['close'].shift(1))
    tr3 = abs(dataTrad['low'] - dataTrad['close'].shift(1))
    **trRange = [tr1, tr2, tr3].max(axis = 1)**
    atr10 = ((atr10.shift(-1) * (10 - 1) + trRange)/10
```

Comment: Can you post a [mcve] and the error message you get?

Comment: Thx  I modify my post with the mre.